# Duplicate class found in modules paytabs

Tags: android, kotlin, paytabs

Duplicate class d.a found in modules jetified-filepicker-1.0.6-runtime (com.github.atwa:filepicker:1.0.6) and jetified-payment-sdk-6.4.12-runtime (com.paytabs:payment-sdk:6.4.12)

Dependcies
implementation 'com.github.atwa:filepicker:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.paytabs:payment-sdk:6.4.12'

Also in gradle properties
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Just Want to run app